# installing and using openssl into a specific path

Tags: macos, command-line, openssl, command-line-interface, homebrew

Need to install a specific version of openssl into a specific directory on my machine. The reason is the project is setup to look for that specific path for the openssl.

After installing `homebrew`, openssl was installed with `brew install openssl`. By default that seems to have stored it in `/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1`

It needs to be in a different path such as `usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1`

Furthermore, after typing `which openssl` it outputs to an `openssl` within a different directory than both of them and the date of creation is two years ago when the laptop was first initialized.

Comment: `/usr/etc` (I assume you forgot the leading `/`?) isn't a normal directory, and on recent versions of macOS the `/usr` directory is on a cryptographically signed read-only volume; if your project expects to find openssl there, there's something seriously wrong with how your project is set up. Also, the version of any program that `which` finds is controlled primarily by your `PATH` environment variable (it determines which directories are searched for command binaries, and in what order).

Comment: the directory is actually `/usr/local/etc`. Forgot to add the `local` part.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Would creating a symlink in `/usr/local/etc` work?